# Android Studio: Dynamically add icon to ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-imageview

Trying to teach myself how to do these things. I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically add an image to a ListView item. What I'm doing is pulling JSON data in that returns the following:

```
{"mdslist":
    [
        {
            "UID":"3",
            "name":"Stamford, CT",
            "date":"March 10, 2018",
            "icon":"badge_stamford"
        },
        {
            "UID":"4",
            "name":"Enschede, The Netherlands",
            "date":"March 11, 2018",
            "icon":"badge_enschede"
        }
    ]
}
```

That data is then processed and dumped into a ListView. The ListView has individual containers to hold the data - note the temporary img in the ImageView tag:

```
md_list_item.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/md_item_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:minHeight="65dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/md_icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/md_logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/badge_stamford" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/md_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/md_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/md_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/md_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/md_name" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The JSON data gets injected during an onPostExecute() call after getting processed:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd.isShowing()) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        /**
         * Dump parsed JSON data into ListView
         **/
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                md_list_all.this, mdList,
                R.layout.md_list_item, new String[]{"name", "date"}, new int[]{R.id.md_name, R.id.md_date});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

As you can see, I have no facility to add the icon data. Those files are named as the JSON data, with a .jpg extension. What I'd like is to grab the JSON 'icon' info, and inject it into the ImageView.

Comment: if those icons are on your server side storage then attach the root url path for the icons with the name of the icon and load the URL into the imageView using GLIDE or Picasso!

Comment: They're not. They're being pulled in locally. Although you do make me wonder if I should put them server side and keep the app light.

Comment: if you put them in client side, you wont be able to update without updating your app in playstore. My suggestion would be like what @Rizwanatta said. When you return JSON from server, provide the url of the icon. Store the path in your list view .When loading image, use glide (you dont need to worry about cache, it takes care of it for subsequent call). You can display spinner untill your icon is loaded if your process takes too much time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice folks. I will look into glide and how that's done.

Answer (score 0):

As Rizwan said in the comments you probably want to use a URL to load the image from a server.

To answer the other part of your question you need to create a custom ListAdapter, SimpleAdapter won't give you much flexibility.

Below I took some code I did in the past and tried to make it easy enough to understand, let me know if you have any questions on it?

```
class AdvancedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<CustomData> mItems;

    AdvancedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CustomData> items) {
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mContext = context;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mItems.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView titleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        titleView.setText(mItems.get(position).name());
        imageView.setImageResource(0); //Nulls out the image while loading
......
...... Load image from URL
imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) finalImage);
.....




        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adam. As I'm still learning Java, I'm getting stuck on different things and then figuring them out as I go. While on the surface I understand your code, trying to inject it into mine is going to be a challenge.

Comment: In this case in particular, I'm trying to figure out where this class definition goes, and how it ties in with filling in the ListView. Aaaaah, I'll start playing ...

Comment: You can make a whole new Java file, and replace the creation of the SimpleAdapter with the new adapter you made. Then you just need to fill out the pieces specific for your views and data. If you get stuck on any specific parts just let us know!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As I am still learning here, I'm trying to understand it all and figuring things out while I go. What you said above makes perfect sense to me, it's a matter of me figuring out how to actually implement that. How classes get called from other files, where I can or can not refer to something ... etc., etc. I'm bad with reading books, I'm better with trial and error (and at times scratching my head.)